# Pasar datos entre componentes distintos en react

Tags: json, reactjs

Mi pregunta es la siguiente como puedo pasar datos de un JSON rescatado en el componente principal

```html
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Video from './Video';

class Home extends Component{
   
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
          dataSource: []
        };
        
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:4000/data'
        fetch(url).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
            let dataSource = [];
            Object.values(responseJson).forEach(item => {
                dataSource = dataSource.concat(item);
            });
            this.setState({dataSource: dataSource})
        });
    }
    handleClick(title){
        console.log(title)
    }
    
    render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <h1>Home</h1>
              { this.state.dataSource.map((dynamicData, i) =>
               
               <div key={ i } className="slide">
                <NavLink to="/Video">
                
                <img width="600px" height="300px"
                onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,dynamicData.title)}
                src={dynamicData.image}
                />
                   
                </NavLink>
                   
                      
                </div>
              )
              *   
          </div>  
        );
    }
    
}

export default Home;
```

& pasar ejemplo **title** a otro componente diferente

```html
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Video extends Component{
    
    render(){
        return(
          <div>
              <h1>TITULO RESCATADO DEL JSON</h1>
          </div>  
        );
    }
}

export default Video;
```

Se los agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Puedes utilizar Redux [https://es.redux.js.org/](https://es.redux.js.org/) así tienes la información centralizada e

Answer (score 1):

La manera que se me ocurre sin utilizar *redux*, es crear un estado nuevo de title.

```
this.state = {
  dataSource: [],
  title : "",
};
```

Cada vez que se ejecute la función handleClick() seteas el title que llega como parámetro a el nuevo estado.

```
handleClick(title){
    this.setState({
        title : title
    });
}
```

Ahora que ya tienes el title almacenado en el estado, lo puedes enviar como propiedad en el componente `Video`.

Tu código en el componente `Home` quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```html
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Video from './Video';

class Home extends Component{
   
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {
          dataSource: [],
          title : "",
        };
        
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:4000/data'
        fetch(url).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
            let dataSource = [];
            Object.values(responseJson).forEach(item => {
                dataSource = dataSource.concat(item);
            });
            this.setState({dataSource: dataSource})
        });
    }
    handleClick(title){
        this.setState({
          title : title
        });
    }
    
    render(){
        const {title} = this.state;
        return(
          <div>
            <h1>Home</h1>
              { this.state.dataSource.map((dynamicData, i) =>
               
               <div key={ i } className="slide">
                <NavLink to="/Video">
                
                <img width="600px" height="300px"
                onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,dynamicData.title)}
                src={dynamicData.image}
                />
                   
                </NavLink>
                   
                      
                </div>
              )
              *
   
          </div>  
        );
    }
    
}

export default Home;
```

Ahora solo es llamar el componente `Video` dónde necesites que se renderice dentro del componente `Home` de la siguiente manera `<Video title={title} />` de esta forma se le esta enviando el título que tenemos almacenado en el estado `title` a el componente `Video`.

El código en el componente `Video` quedaría así, recibimos la propiedad `title` que se le están enviando desde `Home` y la imprimimos en el H1.

```html
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Video extends Component{

render(){
    const {title} = this.props;
    return(
      <div>
          <h1>{title}</h1>
      </div>  
    );
}
}

export default Video;
```